# How do i keep docker container running in background?

Tags: mysql, docker, vagrant

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql \
> -v /mydata/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql \
> -v /mydata/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql \
> -v /mydata/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql \
> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
> -d mysql:5.7
c5d05eeba6d1f848e770968a5a1d806eb9b30a8504522b354283d73dc5bdeb3e
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
c5d05eeba6d1   mysql:5.7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Exited (1) 7 seconds ago             mysql
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker start mysql
mysql
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
[root@localhost vagrant]#
```

I am using vagrant ssh to connect my linux system: centos/7
I tried to add "-it" option, but does not work for me.
does any body know how to fix? thanks!

Comment: anything interesting in `docker logs c5d05eeba6d1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Docker run command runs in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942860/does-docker-run-command-runs-in-background). Also see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.18:3309:3306  --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

You can always use detach tag to run a container in background.

Comment: It works for me, so if it doesn't for you, I guess the problem lies in the volumes that you're mounting. Make sure the directories are correct and see more details with `docker container logs <container-id>`

Comment: why the port is 3309?

Comment: host port is anything you can choose.